# php copy fails without any error message

Tags: php, copy

i was trying to copy some images from url and when i encode that url directly in php copy function it copies without any issue but when i get that as

image url  https://dl.iteens.ir/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/wedding-cake-topper-many-layers-wedding-dress-clay-by-asiaworld-120-242x300.jpg

```
   $decoded = json_decode($content, true);
   $urls = $decoded['url'];
```

and pass $urls in copy it does not work.

```
  copy($urls,'path/img.jpg');
```

I have tested the same with

```
  $myfile = fopen("/something/newfile.txt", "w") 
   fwrite($myfile, $urls);
  fclose($myfile);
```

i can see exact same url written in newfile.txt

but this work

```
  copy('https://dl.iteens.ir/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/wedding-cake-topper-many-layers-wedding-dress-clay-by-asiaworld-120-242x300.jpg','path/img.jpg');
```

i tried different combination of copy like

```
copy("$urls","path/img.jpg");
```

nothing worked for most of the images the copy($urls,'path/img.jpg'); works but not for this link. i dont think its ip block from either server because when we give direct link it works
i further tried by adding fgets($myfile); and tried to copy same thing from text file and it worked so dont know what is the problem

Comment: Compare the URL in `$urls` with `echo $urls`. If PHP doesn't show errors, make sure you use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21429652/4733879) in your PHP script.

Comment: my apologies . this was already there error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: And is `display_errors = on` set correctly in your `php.ini`?

Comment: ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

Comment: Well, `ini_set()` doesn't show parse errors.

Comment: i further tried by adding fgets($myfile); and tried to copy same thing from text file and it worked so dont know what is the problem